# Are there any limits when exporting logs from Cloud Logging?

Tags: google-cloud-logging

I have an operation which has 4,733 resources failed, but when querying from the GCP logs explorer window and downloading them it is not exporting all the logs and only exporting 1392 logs.

So not able to understand as to why this is the case. Is there a limit on the logs exported and how the filter is applied?

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/logging/quotas) the limit was shown as size. I tried to replicate your concern by downloading logs and I was able to download everything.

Try to change the limit of `Maximum Log Entries` to 5000 when you download the logs.
Make sure that you see 4733 log entries in `Query Result`. Query result is where you can see how many logs that it will going to download.

For the filter concern. If you want to check the logs using date and time you can click the tab that has `Last 1 hour` then from there you will have some option to check the logs using date and time.

You can also use the tab `Resource`, `Log Name` and `Severity`. Then click “Run Query” every after filter you’ve made.